# Drawing a bezier curve in d3.js with more than two control points

Tags: css, svg, d3.js, path, bezier

I'm new to d3 and I'm trying to draw a path with a lot of smooth curves; it's supposed to give the impression that the data is vine-like.

However, when trying to draw the paths with bezier curves it seems that you are limited to only quadratic/cubic bezier curves, and you can't add more than two control points, is there a way to add more?

I considered using multiple path elements, giving two control points, an end point, and then drawing a new one from scratch - but the issue with that is that the code is supposed to be able to handle any dataset thrown at it, and if I specify end points I always end up running into sharper angles in the graph.

Comment: SVG only offers cubic and quadradic bezier curves: https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/paths.html#PathDataCubicBezierCommands

Comment: Thank you, I was afraid that was the case

Comment: You should be able to draw any curve you like with multiple beziers though.

Comment: "the issue with that is that the code is supposed to be able to handle any dataset thrown at it" is not a problem, a cubic "polybezier" will work fine. However, "if I specify end points I always end up running into sharper angles in the graph" _that_ is a problem and you should probably show an example of that so we can solve _that_ problem =)

Comment: So you need to smooth your data generated polylines [like in this codepen](https://codepen.io/herrstrietzel/pen/gOKMZRo)?